# Unmount react component from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Other SO threads haven't proved to be useful for me. I have a parent component and 2 child components. Both child components are separate modals. I want to unmount one of the child component when its modal is closed after clicking its close button. Because I want to remount that child component after a certain click event from parent as I have some things to set in the constructor of the child component. Basically, I want to rerun the constructor of a child component (modal) after it has been closed and reopened from the parent component again. Till now the only way I know of solving my problem is unmounting the child component and remounting it after rerendering the parent component.

```
<Parent>
 <Child1 />
 <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

Comment: Unmounting and remounting is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @LuudJacobs Thanks for the confirmation. Can you tell me how I achieve that? Like what should I put in the function that closes my modal?

Comment: Best way is probably to keep a state in your parent component which is used to define what modal (and if a modal) should be opened. Pass the setState() method to the child components so that you can set the state from there (ie by using the close button)